# How do I implement a JavaScript "Discount Redemption Tracking" script for use with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I work for a digital marketing business, and my role is to ensure our partners have a tracking mechanism in place on their order confirmation page which will recognise a certain discount code that has been redeemed by a user, and then make a call to our Tracking API with the appropriate information for that purchase.

To help a partner implement this, we provide sample code in popular languages such as PHP or JavaScript. Where there are only minor amendments to be made to parameters and values based on their website to ensure a successful tracking call.

The problem we are having is that many partners are using Google Tag Manager as a means for making Analytics and Tracking implementations easier for staff who aren't technical enough to hard-code these into their order confirmation page themselves. Currently, we have no distributable tags which will help a GTM user implement this.

We're having trouble trying to work out how to translate, say our JavaScript sample code, into something which can be used by a partner who is using Google Tag Manager. Is there a way to easily translate a JavaScript file into a distributable tag or snippet of code for use with GTM which will allow someone to add it to a specific page?

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this? As no one from our development department has worked with GTM before and we're lacking the resources for a developer to look into the nitty-gritty technical side of this area.

Many thanks with anticipation.

Comment: Host the code on your site and provide partners with a `<script>` tag pointing to your solution.

Comment: How do we configure this to be set up as a distributable tag for our partners to implement?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/setting-google-analytics-fields-in-gtm/ or some of this guys other tips. You should be able to call gtm or analytics from your script with their (google) global variables `ga` or `dataLayer`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purely fictitious example. Host the js on your digital marketing business site. Then have your clients include the script tag pointing to this js.
This js sends some event data to google. I hope this helps to jump start what you need done.

In this example, the clients have the coupon code in a span tag (with a very specific and unique class name) among the content.

```js
(function(coupons) {
  /** This code should be hosted here: danny-parker.com/api/tracking/script.js */
  var sendToGa = function(target) {
    var data = {
      'hitType': 'event',
      'eventCategory': 'Confirmation Page',
      'eventAction': 'Blah Blah Blah Blah',
      'eventLabel': target.innerHTML
    };

    ga('send', data);
    /** alternatively, you could use dataLayer.push(data); */
    return data;
  };

  var couponData = coupons.map(sendToGa);
  window.couponData = couponData;
}(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.danny-parker-coupon-redeemer'))));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Order Confirmation Page - Danny's Partner's website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <span class="danny-parker-coupon-redeemer">123</span>
  <span class="danny-parker-coupon-redeemer">456</span>
  <span class="danny-parker-coupon-redeemer">789</span>
  <span class="danny-parker-coupon-redeemer">011</span>

  <script src="//danny-parker.com/api/tracking/script.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for such a comprehensive suggestion!

Unfortunately due to the nature of the tag being put across any unknown number of sites and frameworks I have no way of ensuring that their discount code will be written in a span identified like that.

Comment: It does not have to be a span tag but there does need to be some kind of consistency.

Comment: In that case, there could me an issue with implementing this within a Google Tag. Thank you for your input though, it is greatly appreciated.